# extract strings and insert as multiple rows based on original index

Tags: python, json, pandas, indexing, insert

I have put example dataset (df), expected output (df2) and my code so far below.
I have a df where some rows in column i2 contain a list - in the json format, which need exploding and reinserting back into the df, from the row in which they were extracted. But the need to be inputted into a different column (i1). i need to extract a unique identifier (the 'id_2' value) from the string and insert that into the id_2 column.

in my code so far i am parsing the json-like data with pd.normalize, and then inserting the original string from the column i1 onto the top of the extracted strings (it should be much more clear if you take a look below) and then reinsert them based on the index. But I have to specify the index, which is not good. I would like it to be less dependent on manual input of indices in case it changes in the future with more of these nested cells or somehow the index changes.

Any suggestions are very welcome, thanks so much

**example data**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'id_2': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'i1': ['How old are you?','Over the last month have you felt','Do you live alone?','In the last week have you had','When did you last visit a doctor?'], 'i2': [0,0,0,0,0]})
df['i2'] = df['i2'].astype('object')

a = [{'id': 'b1', 'item': 'happy?', 'id_2': 'hj59'}, {'id': 'b2', 'item': 'sad?', 'id_2': 'dgb'}, {'id': 'b3', 'item': 'angry?', 'id_2':'kj9'}, {'id': 'b4', 'item': 'frustrated?','id2':'lp7'}]
b = [{'id': 'c1', 'item': 'trouble sleeping?'}, {'id': 'c2', 'item': 'changes in appetite?'}, {'id': 'c3', 'item': 'mood swings?'}, {'id': 'c4', 'item': 'trouble relaxing?'}]

df.at[1, 'i2'] = a 
df.at[3, 'i2'] = b
```

**expected output**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5], 
                         'id_2': ['a','hj59','dgb','kj9','lp7','c','d','d','d','d','e'],
                         'i1': ['How old are you?',
                                'Over the last month have you felt happy?',
                                'Over the last month have you felt sad?',
                                'Over the last month have you felt angry?',
                                'Over the last month have you felt frustrated?',
                                'Do you live alone?',
                                'In the last week have you had trouble sleeping?',
                                'In the last week have you had changes in appetite?',
                                'In the last week have you had mood swings?',
                                'In the last week have you had trouble relaxing?',
                                'When did you last visit a doctor?'], 
                         'i2': [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]})
```

**my ugly code so far**

```
s={}
s = df[df.i2 != 0]

n={}

for i in range(len(s)):
    n[i] = pd.json_normalize(s.loc[s.index[i]]['i2']).reset_index(inplace=False, drop=False)  
    n[i]['i1'] = s.iloc[i].i1 + ' ' + n[i]['item']
    def insert_row(i, d1, d2): return d1.iloc[:i, ].append(d2)
    for i in n:
        if i == 0:
            x = insert_row(s.iloc[i].name, df, n[i])
        elif i == 1:
            x = insert_row(s.iloc[i].name+1+n[i]['index'].count()+1, x, n[i]) 
            y = x.append(df.iloc[s.iloc[i].name+1:, ])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Explode` the dataframe on column `i2`, then retrieve the values associated with key `item` from the column `i2` using the `str` accessor, then using indexing with `loc` update the values in column `i2`  to `1` and concatenate the strings in `i1` with the retrieved item values

```
df2 = df.explode('i2', ignore_index=True)
s = df2['i2'].str['item']
df2.loc[s.notna(), 'i2'] =  1
df2.loc[s.notna(), 'i1'] += ' ' + s
```

---

```
    id                                                  i1 i2
0    1                                    How old are you?  0
1    2            Over the last month have you felt happy?  1
2    2              Over the last month have you felt sad?  1
3    2            Over the last month have you felt angry?  1
4    2       Over the last month have you felt frustrated?  1
5    3                                  Do you live alone?  0
6    4     In the last week have you had trouble sleeping?  1
7    4  In the last week have you had changes in appetite?  1
8    4          In the last week have you had mood swings?  1
9    4     In the last week have you had trouble relaxing?  1
10   5                   When did you last visit a doctor?  0
```

Comment: just simple and awesome

Comment: thank you so much! thats amazing. very elegant. I posted an update as i realised that for some of the nested cells there is an additional item i need to extract and put in to another column - i am trying to get it out but i cant. perhaps you could help?

Comment: oh wow its late in the day - its just something like this isn't it? d = df2['i2'].str['id_2']

Comment: Yes it is! You can retrieve any value present in the dictionary using the `str` accessor